# Adding Non-existing entity from Doctrine 2 many to many relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, many-to-many, multi-select

I want to add new non existing entity in database from multi-select form element.

**Scenario** is that, I have a multi select option in my form where user can select multiple persons. when user  insert a keyword in multi select, i send ajax request to server to fetch results, if no result is found then user has can add new preson with same multi select. **My form has many-to-many relationship**. Below is the ui of my form.

[image]

As you can see i select to persons in multi select. ***Aneeq*** and ***Tariq Najib***. But ***aneeq*** is an existing entity in database and on the other hand ***Tariq Najib*** is a non existing entity (New entity).

What i want to do is when i submit form, first doctrine have to add ***Tariq Najib*** in the table and then associate ***Tariq Najib*** to the other entity. Below is the code of multi select element.

```
<option value="1" selected >aneeq</option>
<option value="" selected >Tariq Najib</option>
```

And how doctrine Hydrator will help me to achieve this problem.

The perfect example of my problem is stackoverflow's tags system. we can add new tag if the tag is not already exist in the database.

Comment: You may want to check this link that may help you https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#example-3--onetomany-association

Comment: i already see this documentation and implemented on my other scenario and worked fine with text field. but in this my problem, i have multi select when i submit my form it pass the ids of the entities. and doctrine hydrator use these entity to fetch object. But new entity doesn't have id yet.

Comment: You could add new entity when check if tag exist (if not make new entity and return this just like aneeq)